# Is there a fiddler like app for IPhone to see what HTTP calls are being made?

Tags: iphone

This is for troubleshooting my app on IPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without jailbreaking the phone.

However, you could use an upstream proxy.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.httpwatch.com/
Free version is good, but to get the info you real info you will need the "pro" version.